# Azure Devops - How to Add an extra Deployment Type from drop down list inside Release pipeline Options

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

do you know a way to add an extra Deployment Type from drop down list inside Release pipeline Options ?
from the Drop down I want to add Staging2 as we have 2 Staging environments 
the other options available does not match (production, testing, unmapped, ...)
We use Staging one for our Staging env. but not option match for our Staging2 environment

Comment: Is this drop down the "[Report deployment status to Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/work-item-deployments-control?view=azure-devops)" in release pipeline options? If so, i don't think you can add custom items in it and it's just a deployment type which should not affect which staging environment you want to target.

Comment: Yes this is the drop down I'm talking about. As I report the status to the Board, its more useful to have 2 distinguish entries rather than twice Staging.
this is why I'm trying to get new Staging2 entry

Comment: Hi, I've posted an answer and sorry to tell this is not possible at current time. But this should be the answer for the quesion, you can accept it if it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

> add an extra Deployment Type from drop down list inside Release pipeline Options

This seems not possible, at least not possible at current time.

As mentioned in [this article](https://thecloudhub.com/2019/07/how-to-link-azure-devops-with-jira/):

*These deployment types are set by Microsoft, and you’ll have to pick from the list and match them as best you can to your stages.*

*At present, there are 5 deployment types:*

- *Production*
- *Staging*
- *Testing*
- *Development*
- *Unmapped*